# ASP.NET Core publish - Blank screen in Console no errors

Tags: c#, serilog, asp.net-core-6.0, kestrel-http-server

I have an ASP.NET Core 6.0 Web API. When I publish it and run the exe, a console window opens and nothing happens after that. Usually we get port number where application is hosted and I can run in the browser  to access the url. This issue happens only after publishing and running the `.exe`. When debugging, it is fine.

I have troubleshooted further, issue identified is that I have added Serilog in the start up and that is causing the issue. If I remove Serilog things, it is again working as expected.

Code for setting up Serilog

```
public static void ConfigureSerilog(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Read Configuration from appSettings
    var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .Build();
    log = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .ReadFrom.Configuration(config)
            .CreateLogger();
    Log.Logger = log;
    log.Information("API Started");

    services.AddLogging(loggingBuilder =>
        {
            loggingBuilder.ClearProviders();
            loggingBuilder.AddSerilog();
        });
}
```

No errors can be found in Event viewer. If add console working expected what am I doing wrong and how can we make the exe run with Serilog configured?

Comment: am not using IIS am using kestrel(running exe)